# How do you pour a bottle conditioned beer?

Tags: pouring, bottle-conditioning

Bottle conditioned beers (such as many homebrews or those explicitly labelled as bottle conditioned/fermented) are, I'm told, supposed to be poured a specific way to avoid getting the yeast from the bottle into the glass.  How should I pour such a beer?

Bonus points for gifs or diagrams I can distribute with my homebrew.  :)

Answer (score 10):

[image: Pour a beer]

When pouring a beer with sediment, or lees, make sure your glass is of a size to accommodate the full contents of the bottle plus the attendant foam. Pour smoothly into the glass, watching the neck of the bottle, and suspend pouring when you see sediment starting to come to the neck. If you haven’t screwed it up, you have a glass of clear, inviting beer. Well done.

Answer (score 10):

[image]

<sup>Unfortunately, I don't know the source of this image—a Google reverse image search reveals only a single webpage which itself attributes the image to Google searching.</sup>